# Java issues with Scanner and hasNextLine() while reading a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am having an issue with this unfinished program. I do not understand why this returns a "no Line found exception" when I run it. I have a while loop set up whose purpose is checking for this but I have done something wrong. I am trying to store information from a file into a 2d array for class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int NUM_CHARACTERS = 26;      // Maximum number of letters
      int MAX_WORDS = 10;           // Maximum number of synonyms per starting letter
      String userWord = (scnr.next()) + ".txt"; //Get word user wants to search
      char userChar = scnr.next().charAt(0); //Get char user wants to search
      String[][] synonyms = new String[NUM_CHARACTERS][MAX_WORDS];  // Declare 2D array for all synonyms
      String[] words = new String[MAX_WORDS]; // The words of each input line
      
      File aFile = new File(userWord);
      
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(aFile);
      
      while(inFile.hasNextLine()) {
         for(int i = 0; i < synonyms.length; i++) {
            words = inFile.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
            for(int wordCount = 0; wordCount < words.length; wordCount++) {
               synonyms[i][wordCount] = words[wordCount];
            }
         }
      }
      
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess I know what's wrong but I need to see the error log for confirmation. Can you add the error log please?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
 at LabProgram.main(LabProgram.java:23)

Comment: check the answer I've posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your problem is that you're only checking `hasNextLine()` before the `for` loop starts, and you're actually *getting* the next line on every iteration of the loop. So if you run out of lines while in the middle of your `for` loop an exception is thrown.

I'm actually not quite sure what your code is supposed to do but at the very least you need to add a `hasNextLine()` check **every time** before you actually run `nextLine()` to avoid errors like this.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this. The idea is to select a file based on user provided input of a word. The program should read that file which contains synonyms for the word listed line by line alphabetically and store it in a 2d array. After it has stored the information I need to pull and print the words stored in the 2d array for the user provided character. I understand the issue now and should be able to finish. I appreciate your patience, if it's not clear I am new to this!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < synonyms.length; i++) {
    words = inFile.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
    ....
}
```

You're iterating from `i=0` upto `synonym.length-1` times, but that file does not have these much lines, so, as soon as your file is out of lines but the for loop has scope to iterate more, the `inFile.nextLine()` gets no line and thus throw the exception.

I don't know what you are exactly doing here or want to achieve through this code, but this is what causing you the trouble.

Hope that answers your query.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this.